Extracting URL from a LinkedIn user's post using URN or another way
I'm seeking assistance in retrieving the actual URL from a LinkedIn user's post using the URN (Not organization). Is there any way to accomplish this? I'm unsure about how to extract the URL, so any guidance or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and help!
I attempted to extract the URL of a LinkedIn user's post using the URN through the LinkedIn API. However, I'm unsure of the correct approach to achieve this. So far, I haven't been able to retrieve the desired URL. Therefore, I'm seeking advice and alternative methods from the community to accomplish this task. Any help provided would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
